# Excel ExportAsFixedFormat(PDF) adding extra empty sheets in exported PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, office-interop, excel-interop

I have successfully exported PDF of excel file using Excel `ExportAsFixedFormat()` but this method adds extra empty sheet with each sheet. If I save the workbook as excel file it do not contain any extra sheet. The used range of sheets is From **A1-B6** so only 12 cells in use.
Here is how I am exporting excel workbook to PDF.

```
xlNewWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
userSpecificFile, missing, missing, true, missing, 
missing, missing, missing);
```

I am not being able to figure out why its adding these extra empty sheets.

Comment: You are most likely printing blank columns. Where do you end up if you tap [Ctrl]+[End}? Is it outside the 'printing area'? Have you set up the Page Layout, Page Setup, Print Area? If you specify Page Setup, Sheet, Print row and column labels can you identify what area is being printed?

Comment: @Jeeped: thanks for the hint, setting up page layout in code worked. by setting 'PageSetup.FitToPagesTall and PageSetup.FitToPagesWide

Comment: @AdilWaqar can you please tell me where do I have to put those lines ?

Comment: @lennin92: I have added this code before exporting the excel workbook